# Inconsistent play behavior in sandbox iframes - some songs play, some songs don't

Tags: soundcloud

See this JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/40qjdsan/

The Rihanna song plays without sandboxing, but throws a JS error when in sandbox.

Problematic iframe:

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms" width="100%" height="200" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/67658191&amp;auto_play=false&amp;buying=false&amp;liking=true&amp;download=false&amp;sharing=true&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;show_comments=false&amp;show_playcount=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;hide_related=false&amp;visual=false&amp;start_track=0&amp;callback=true">
  </iframe>
```

The Dire Straits song plays fine in both instances.

Any ideas on how to get this to work in sandboxed version all the time?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Not sure why soundcloud has different results for sanbox mode on iframes.